# Automatic javascript console

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

Chrome has dev toools and a javascript console. I want any website visited in Chrome to execute this simple javascript code: `alert("hi")`

Comment: Take a look at [Content scripts](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts)

Answer (score 0):

From what I gather, you want to run a Javascript command everything you enter a website?

If so, then you can use the Chrome extension Tampermonkey, write a custom script, tell it to trigger every time it detects a change in the window.location variable and run said script.